# Docker in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am creating a node.js(angular/cli) application and want to run the tests by using docker container. I successfully created docker image and uploaded to docker hub where it runs automated build after each commit.

The problem is: I don't know what to put in bitbucket-pipelines.yml file.
I want that after each commit it would take a newly built container from dockerhub and run the tests against it.

Also, I want to minimize bitbucket build time.

Answer (score 0):

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        image: [Enter your docker image here, as on hub.docker.com]
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm install -g @angular/cli
          - ng build --prod
          - ls -ltr
          - pwd
```